# Console gives error regarding pickPhone being undefined

Tags: javascript, html, css

First actual project, I've got the baseline done and about to start consulting with a friend regarding recommendations, but no matter how much I try to make this work, console gives this error:
Uncaught ReferenceError: pickPhone is not defined
at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            margin: 0;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            height: 100vh;
        }
        .DivBox {
            border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
            background-color: #f5f5f5;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 20px;
            width: 100%;
            border-radius: 25px;
            box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #6b6b6b;
        }   
        .DivTextTitle {
            font-family: Helvetica;
            font-size: 56px
        }
        .DivTextBody {
            font-family: Helvetica;
            font-size: 28px;
            margin: 20px;
        }
        .DivPicker {
            display: inline-block;
            position:relative;
            width: 100%;
        }
        .CustomDropdown {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 10px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            border-radius: 5px;
            background-color: #fff;
            font-size: 16px;
            cursor: pointer;
            box-shadow: 2.5px 2.5px 2px #6b6b6b;
            font-size: 28px;
        }
        .CustomDropdown select {
            width: calc(100% - 20px);
            border: none;
            outline: none;
            appearance: none;
            background-color: transparent;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        .DivButton {
            border:none;
            color: white;
            padding: 16px 32px;
            text-align: center;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: inline-block;
            font-size: 36px;
            margin: 4px 2px;
            transition-duration: 0.5s;
            cursor: pointer;
            margin: 20px;
        }
        .DivButton1 {
            background-color: #e6e6e6;
            color: black;
            border: 2px #e6e6e6;
            border-radius: 5px;
            box-shadow: 2.5px 2.5px 2px #6b6b6b;
            margin: 20px;
            padding: 20px 40px;
            font-size: 28px;
        }
        .DivButton1:hover {
            background-color: #bdbdbd;
            color: black;
        }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="DivBox">
<div class="DivTextTitle">Pick a Phone</div>
<div class="DivTextBody">Select options from these 5 categories and our cleverly made site will pick a phone that is perfect for you!</div>
<div class="DivTextBody">What do you value most in a phone?</div>
<div class="DivTextBody">
    <label for="Preference"></label>
    <div class="CustomDropdown">
    <select name="Preference" id="pref">
        <option value="disp">Display</option>
        <option value="perf">Performance</option>
        <option value="cam">Cameras</option>
        <option value="bat">Battery</option>
        <option value="over">No strong preference</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="DivTextBody">What is your budget?</div>
<div class="DivTextBody">
    <label for=Budget></label>
    <div class="CustomDropdown">
    <select name="Budget" id="budg">
        <option value="1">100-200€</option>
        <option value="2">200-300€</option>
        <option value="3">300-400€</option>
        <option value="4">400-500€</option>
        <option value="5">500-600€</option>
        <option value="6">600-700€</option>
        <option value="7">700-800€</option>
        <option value="8">800-900€</option>
        <option value="9">900-1000€</option>
        <option value="10">1000-1200€</option>
        <option value="11">1200+€</option>
    </select>
</div><div class="DivTextBody">Which company made your current phone?</div>
<div class="DivTextBody">
    <label for=CuPh></label>
    <div class="CustomDropdown">
    <select name="CuPh" id=CuPh>
        <option value="Apple">Apple</option>
        <option value="Samsung">Samsung</option>
        <option value="Google">Google</option>
        <option value="Xiaomi Group">Xiaomi/Redmi/Poco</option>
        <option value="Oppo">Oppo</option>
        <option value="OnePlus">OnePlus</option>
        <option value="Realme">Realme</option>
        <option value="Vivo">Vivo</option>
        <option value="Sony">Sony</option>
        <option value="Other">Other</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="DivTextBody">How many other products from this company do you have?</div>
<div class="DivTextBody">
    <label for=CuAc></label>
    <div class="CustomDropdown">
    <select name="CuAc" id=CuAc>
        <option value="0">None</option>
        <option value="1">1-2</option>
        <option value="2">3-4</option>
        <option value="3">5+</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="DivTextBody">Do you prefer customisation or reliability?</div>
<div class="DivTextBody">
    <label for="CR"></label>
    <div class="CustomDropdown">
    <select name="CR" id=CR>
        <option value="C">Customisation</option>
        <option value="R">Reliablity</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="DivTextBody">So, what are you waiting for?</div>
<button class="button DivButton1" onclick="pickPhone()">Pick a Phone!</button>
<div id="phonePopup" class="popup">
<span class="close" onclick="closePopup()">&times;</span>
<div id="SelectedPhone">Selected Phone: </div>
</div>

<script>
        function pickPhone() {
            var preference = document.getElementById("pref").value;
            var budget = document.getElementById("budg").value;
            var company = document.getElementById("CuPh").value;
            var numProducts = document.getElementById("CuAc").value;
            var customization = document.getElementById("CR").value;

            var selectedPhone = determinePhone(preference, budget, company, numProducts, customization);

            document.getElementById("SelectedPhone").innerText = "You have selected: " + selectedPhone;

            document.getElementById("phonePopup").style.display = "block";
        }

function determinePhone(preference, budget, company, numProducts, customization) {
    var phoneOptions = [
        { criteria: { preference: 'Apple', budget: '<1000'}, phone: "iPhone 15"},
        { criteria: { preference: 'Apple', budget: '<1200'}, phone: "iPhone 15 Pro"},
        { criteria: { preference: 'Apple', budget: '>1200'}, phone: "iPhone 15 Pro Max"},
        { criteria: { budget: '<100' }, phone: "Redmi 10C" },
        { criteria: { budget: '<200' }, phone: "Redmi Note 13" },
        { criteria: { budget: '<300' }, phone: "Redmi Note 13 Pro+"},
        { criteria: { budget: '<400' }, phone: "Poco F5"},
        { criteria: { budget: '<500' }, phone: "Poco F5 Pro"},
        { criteria: { preference: 'perf', budget: '<700'}, phone: "Poco F5 Pro"},
        { criteria: { preference: 'cam', budget: '<700' }, phone: "Xiaomi 13T"},
        { criteria: { preference: 'disp', budget: '<700' }, phone: "Xiaomi 13T"},
        { criteria: { preference: 'bat', budget: '<700' }, phone: "Xiaomi 13T"},
        { criteria: { preference: 'over', budget: '<700' }, phone: "Xiaomi 13T"}, 
        { criteria: { budget: '<800' }, phone: "Xiaomi 13T Pro"},
        { criteria: { budget: '<1000'}, phone: "Xiaomi 14"},
        { criteria: { budget: '<1200'}, phone: "Xiaomi 14 Pro"},
        { criteria: { budget: '>1200'}, phone: "Xiaomi 14 Ultra"}
    ];

    var selectedPhone = phoneOptions.find(option => {
        return Object.keys(option.criteria).every(key => {
            const value = option.criteria[key];
            return Array.isArray(value) ? value.includes(company) : evaluateCriteria(value, company);
        });
    });

    return selectedPhone ? selectedPhone.phone : "ERROR";
}



            var selectedPhone = phoneOptions.find(option => {
            return Object.keys(option.criteria).every(key => {
                const value = option.criteria[key];
                return evaluateCriteria(value, company);
            });
        });

            return selectedPhone ? selectedPhone.phone : "ERROR";

function evaluateCriteria(expected, actual) {
    if (Array.isArray(expected)) {
        return expected.includes(actual);
    } else if (expected.startsWith('<')) {
        return parseInt(actual) < parseInt(expected.substring(1));
    } else if (expected.startsWith('>=')) {
        return parseInt(actual) >= parseInt(expected.substring(2));
    } else {
        return actual === expected;
    }
}




        function closePopup() {
            document.getElementById("phonePopup").style.display = "none";
        }
};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

So far I've tried going over the entire code and seeing if I formatted everything right, but my beginner eyes can't see any issues.
It should display the phone recommendation upon pressing the button, but it doesn't do anything and in console gives error:
Uncaught ReferenceError: pickPhone is not defined
at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Comment: Firstly this is not valid HTML, so lets fix that first. Strong chance its related. There a several missing `</div>` closing tags. Use a editor with proper HTML linting support or an online tool.

Comment: [Here is my attempt at fixing the HTML structure](https://t.ly/DB7U6). Report back if it made any difference.

Comment: @adsy I've tried the updated structure, doesn't seem to fix it. It still gives the same error upon button being pressed